# How to change Rocket.Chat User Presence to online via RestApi

Tags: rest, delphi, rocket.chat

I work with Delphi 10.2 and Rocket Chat. How can I set the User Presence from offline to online when the user logs in. The login via Delphi and Postman is success. The answer [from docs](https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/realtime-api/method-calls/user-presence/) is to make it via method call but I don't know how.

```json
{
    "msg": "method",
    "method": "UserPresence:setDefaultStatus",
    "id": "42",
    "params": ["online"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are looking at the docs for the real time api.  If you aren’t familiar with it or only need a one off action I would suggest just using the REST API.

```
curl -H "X-Auth-Token: 9HqLlyZOugoStsXCUfD_0YdwnNnunAJF8V47U3QHXSq" \
     -H "X-User-Id: aobEdbYhXfu5hkeqG" \
     http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users.setStatus -d '{"status": "busy"}'
```

This end point is actually new I think added in Rocket.Chat 1.2

Of course make sure to authenticate before hand.  More info about that can be found there in the docs as well.

Comment: This works perfect. But the rocket.chat documentary might not have all the REST API commands, like this one. Where did you find it to see if they add something else?

Comment: I just took a look through the PRs.  The documentation should definitely be updated

Comment: @PanMilkos I think this is for the user who logged in. Is it possible to setStatus for other users manually by the admin person. I am using PHP. Thanks

Comment: {
    "success": false,
    "error": "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
} I got this error in version 3.0.0 of rocket chat